# Python Iteration to show specific data only

Tags: python

How can I iterate in 2d list. The output will be the rank and its corresponding name for mythic only?

```
rank = ['mythic', 'epic', 'mythic', 'epic', 'barbarian' ]
name = ['alex', 'baron', 'kino', 'oika', 'tulits']

name_and_rank_zip = zip(rank,name)
name_and_rank_unzip = list(name_and_rank_zip)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please post your expected output instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: pls  provide the output you want its unclear from your question

Comment: Thanks, sir.  I don't know if this is possible. I'm new to programing

The output should look like this.

[('mythic', 'alex'), ('mythic', 'kino',)]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to iterate the two lists simultaneously, and then filter them using list comprehension:

```py
rank = ['mythic', 'epic', 'mythic', 'epic', 'barbarian' ]
name = ['alex', 'baron', 'kino', 'oika', 'tulits']

output = [(r, n) for r, n in zip(rank, name) if r == 'mythic']
print(output) # [('mythic', 'alex'), ('mythic', 'kino')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not yet on the list of comprehension lessons but this works perfectly